# what do logiacal && and || do outside parantheses?

Tags: javascript, logic

I saw a javascript code like this

```
if (a_condition_is_true){
//do this;
//annd this;
var1||var2;
var3 && var4 = var5  // or somthing like that

}
```

so as in the title what do logiacal && and || do outside parantheses??
thanks
EDIT

```
if(a_variable<>a_value){//is that operator (<> not equal !=)legal or not for i saw it before 
//do somthing
}
```

Comment: Same thing they do inside parenthesis

Comment: ok let's assume that we have tha code in question if the var1 is true what will happen to `var2`  and if `var3` and `var4` ar not equal to `var5`     after executing this code   wil they be the same as `var5` ???

Comment: The code in the question doesn't make any sense, `var1||var2` doesn't really return the result anywhere, so it does nothing, and `var3 && var4 = var5` is what's called an invalid left hand assigment, in other words it's a syntax error.

Comment: but if we turn all vars to funcs will probably be

Comment: Doesn't matter if the variables are functions that return truthy/falsy values, the way you've written it the first OR does not return the result anywhere so it does nothing in that context, but the meaning is straight forward, `IF var1 OR var2`, i.e. use `var1` if truthy, otherwise go with `var2`, but you have to actually use it for something, just typing it somewhere does nothing. The second example is just a syntax error no matter how you twist and turn it.

Comment: you seem to be having issues with posting valid code.  In your first question, you had a few statements that were valid and a few that were not valid.  Here you ask a similar, more focused question, but have invalid code related to the operators you had valid code for in the first question.  i.e. `v1&&v2||v1='something'` makes sense, `var3 && var4 = var5` does not.

Comment: Andrew Counts && you are here to put me on hold now again lol

Comment: I didn't do the hold on the first question, it was there before I made my first comment.  We are all trying to help you to become better by discovering how posting valid code can help you answer your own questions.

Answer (score 4):

Since

```
var1||var2;
```

means "evaluate var1 and use its result if truthy, otherwise evaluate var2 and use its result", it is equivalent to

```
if (!var1) { var2; }
```

Comment: IMHO, the explanation would be clearer if you replaced the OP's use of "var" with "expression".

Answer (score 0):

In languages without short-circuiting, they don't do anything.

However, most languages do have short-circuiting, which means that for an OR, if the first condition is true, then it never evaluates the second.  And then for an AND, if the first condition is false, it never evaluates the second.

|| and && also serve as syntactic sugar in dynamic languages where undefined is falsey, such as JavaScript.  For instance, if you have a property on an object that might be null, and you want to check a property on that, you can so something like:

```
if (obj.prop1 && obj.prop1.prop2) { ... }
```

Or to set default values you can do something like

```
var j = thisMightBeNull || "default value";
```